# In IoT Core, section what does massive-carrier mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In IoT Core, "Create a registry" section, in the "Select a Cloud Pub / Sub topic" box, what does massive-carrier mean?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments ... they have enlightened me a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

The **massive-carrier** must be an existing pub/sub topic within your project as the only available option is the name of your pub/sub topics. Refer to the following images:

[Create a registry -> Cloud Pub/Sub topics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWAb.png)

[Complete reference of Cloud Pub/Sub topics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XXIb.png)

I took a look into the documentation and it mention that a [device registry](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/overview) is a container of devices with shared properties, you can "register" a device with a service (like Cloud IoT Core) so that you can manage it. Consider that you must create at least one device registry to use Cloud IoT Core which is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices?&_ga=2.253547338.-211624714.1610681689#creating_a_device_registry_with_multiple_pubsub_topics).

Having said that, a registry can have one or more [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) topics to which devices in the registry can publish data. You can see the following [End-to-end](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/end-to-end-sample) example to build a simple but complete virtual IoT system.